# fillOval() is not taking class variables?

Tags: java, paintcomponent, pong

I'm not sure why but in my paintComponent method, the fillOval function is not letting me pass in my other classes coordinates. It comes up with :

'Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException'

all the rectangles draw fine but just not the oval. Here is the paintComponent() method.

```
     public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics){
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.fillRect(0,0,600,450);

    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    graphics.fillRect(290,0,15,450);
    graphics.fillRect(leftPaddle.getXPos(),leftPaddle.getYPos(),10,85);
    graphics.fillRect(rightPaddle.getXPos(),rightPaddle.getYPos(),10,85);
    graphics.fillOval(ball.getxPos(),ball.getyPos(),ball.getWidth(),ball.getHeight());
}
```

And here is my Ball class (the class which bears the coordinates).

```
public class Ball {
int xPos = 140;
int yPos = 50;
int width = 15;
int height = 15;

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int getxPos() {
    return xPos;
}

public int getyPos() {
    return yPos;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}
```

}

This is probably quite an easy fix, but I am relatively new to java, so excuse any formatting mistakes, etc.

Here is where I get the object from the MainClass :

```
public class PaintComponents extends JPanel{
Paddle leftPaddle;
Paddle rightPaddle;
Ball ball;

public PaintComponents(Paddle leftPaddle, Paddle rightPaddle, Ball ball) {
    this.leftPaddle = leftPaddle;
    this.rightPaddle = rightPaddle;
    this.ball = ball;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As its showing NullPointerException
you might not have created the object "ball" of class Ball
try adding:

```
Ball ball=new Ball();
```

in    `public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics)`

before using "ball".

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver! Yes I see it now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see where did you get the `ball`. So,

1. You can instantiate the Ball class like `Ball ball = new ball()` before the `fillOval()` happen. Or
2. You can mark all the fields and methods as `static` then use `Ball.getSth()` instead.

Comment: Yes Ran, sorry I didn't put that in there, yes I used, Ball ball = new Ball(); but yet it still does not work.

Comment: oops. it should be `Ball ball = new Ball()`. my mistake.